# How would I add a legend entry for each column of pandas dataframe in graph generated by df.boxplot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

trying to create some boxplots of pandas dataframes.

I have dataframes that typically [look like this (not sure if there was a good way to show it so just took a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5yPU.png).

I am creating a boxplot for each dataframe (after transposing) using the df.boxplot() method, it comes out almost exactly how I want it using the code below:

```
ax = crit_storm_df[tp_cols].T.boxplot()
    
ax.set_xlabel("Duration (m)")
ax.set_ylabel("Max Flow (cu.m/sec")
    
    
ax.set_xlim(0, None)
ax.set_ylim(0, None)
    
ax.set_title(crit_storm_df.name)
plt.show()
```

[Example pic of output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nba2j.png). What's lacking though is I want to add a legend with one entry for each box that represents a column in my dataframe in the pic above. Since I transposed the df before plotting, I would like to have a legend entry for each row, i.e. "tp01", "tp02" etc.

Anyone know what I should be doing instead? Is there a way to do this through the df.boxplot() method or do I need to do something in matplotlib?

I tried ax.legend() but it doesn't do anything except give me a warning:

```
No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Aren't the box already plotted using all columns? How would a single value be represented as a box?

Comment: @Tranbi each column is being plotted as one box in the figure. I want each box to be labelled according to its column name.

Comment: If your x-axis is correct, there is a box for each row, and not column

Comment: Ah sorry you are right. I transposed the df before I plotted. But I do want a legend entry for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want your boxes to have different colors, you can use seaborn. It's default behavior there:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df)
plt.legend(ax.patches, df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Edit: adding legend

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I definitely considered it and this would have been the way to go. However, I want to keep using matplotlib since its available by default in QGIS' python env and I might convert my app into a QGIS plugin for my coworkers. Btw, would it be possible to easily show in seaborn a legend with entries col1-4 in your example?

Comment: It's a bit redundant since you already have the columns on the x-axis, but you can do it with `plt.legend(ax.patches, df.columns)`. Check my edited answer! If you want to stick to mpl see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html

Comment: Thanks, I realized I was misunderstanding what I was doing lol. It doesn't make sense to label the boxes as 'tp' if they're showing duration. Which is pretty obvious in hindsight, your comment helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

To get similar type of required graph this code is help you to do that :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Duration': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 180, 270, 360],
    'tp01': [13.1738, 13.1662, 14.3903, 14.2772, 14.3223, 12.5686, 14.8710, 8.9785, 9.2224, 7.4957, 3.6493, 5.7982],
    'tp02': [13.1029, 14.2570, 16.5373, 12.6589, 11.0455, 12.6777, 8.1715, 9.3830, 8.3498, 6.0930, 6.4310, 7.4538],
    'tp03': [14.5263, 13.6724, 11.4800, 13.4982, 12.3987, 11.6688, 10.4089, 7.0736, 5.8004, 10.1354, 5.5874, 5.6749],
    'tp04': [14.7589, 11.6993, 12.5825, 13.5627, 11.9481, 10.7803, 8.9388, 5.7076, 12.7690, 9.7546, 9.5004, 5.9912],
    'tp05': [15.5543, 14.1007, 11.7304, 13.3218, 12.4318, 9.5237, 11.9014, 5.6778, 14.2627, 3.7422, 6.4555, 3.3458],
    'tp06': [13.5196, 12.5939, 12.5679, 11.4414, 9.3590, 9.6083, 9.6704, 10.5239, 9.1028, 6.0336, 7.0258, 5.9800],
    'tp07': [14.7476, 13.3925, 13.0324, 13.3649, 14.7832, 8.1078, 7.1307, 15.4406, 5.0187, 6.9497, 3.6492, 4.8642],
    'tp08': [13.3995, 14.3639, 12.7579, 10.6844, 10.3281, 10.2541, 8.8257, 8.8773, 8.3498, 5.7315, 7.8469, 6.7316],
    'tp09': [16.7954, 17.1788, 15.9850, 10.8780, 12.5249, 10.2174, 7.5735, 7.3753, 7.1157, 4.8536, 9.1581, 5.6369],
    'tp10': [15.7671, 16.1570, 11.6122, 15.2340, 13.2356, 13.2270, 11.6810, 7.1157, 8.0048, 5.5782, 6.0876, 5.7982],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("Duration")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.T.plot(kind='box', ax=ax)

labels = df.columns
lines = [plt.Line2D([0, 1], [0, 1], color=c, marker='o', markersize=10) for c in plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][:len(labels)]]
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')

ax.set_xlabel("Duration (m)")
ax.set_ylabel("Max Flow (cu.m/sec")

ax.set_xlim(0, None)
ax.set_ylim(0, None)

ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)

plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: that graph does not match my output graph. Duration is the index (should be on the x axis).

Comment: Code edited for get required output on x-axis.